# how to make an element inside a variable

Tags: xslt

XSLT 1.0
   I will need a variable with the following structure, basically I need to construct a variable which actually is a element. I know it looks silly but I need such thing because of the limitation of other stuff.

```
 <xsl:variable name="options">
                <xsl:element name="option">
                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                            <xsl:text>test1</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>

                       <xsl:text>test1</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:element>
        </xsl:variable>
```

Now the problem is, when I call it later in the template with

```
<xsl:value-of select="$options"/>
```

the output html only have test1 instead of what I want

```
<option>test1</option>
```

So it means the tag is missing. What's the right syntax to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just FYI, your example seems a bit strange. It's **very** rare to actually **need** the xsl:element tag.  You could rewrite this as `<xsl:variable name="options"><option value="test1">test1</option></xsl:variable>`

Answer (score 2):

**You need to make difference between `<xsl:value-of>` and `<xsl:copy-of>`**

In XSLT 1.0 the `<xsl:value-of>` instruction creates a text node that contains the *string value* of the result of evaluating the XPath expression, specified in the `select` attribute. By definition, the string value of an element is the concatenation (in document order) of all of its descendent text nodes -- this is how you get the string `"test1"` output.

By contrast:

```
<xsl:copy-of>
```

outputs a copy of every node of the node-set that is selected by the XPath expression specified in the `select` attribute.

Therefore, in order to copy the complete contents of `$options`, you need to specify:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$options" />
```

**Here is a complete example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vOptions">
  <option value="test1">test1</option>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$vOptions"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<option value="test1">test1</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$options" />
```